# Including a directory inside web-inf/lib in tomcat classpath

Tags: java, tomcat, classpath, tomcat6

In my webapp; WEB-INF/lib is added in classpath  by default which is fine.
Now, I want to add spring jar files in my tomcat's classpath. If I put all the jar files inside WEB-INF/lib; it works fine. But if I want to add a directory WEB-INF/lib/spring and put all jar files inside spring directory ; it doesnt work. How can I include WEB-INF/lib/spring in classpath.

I would prefer to make changes in web.xml as that is very localised to my webapp. Surely I will not want to make changes in catalina.properties because there all the jar files are loaded in JVM ( not just added in classpath )

Comment: Isn't that what the %CATALINA_HOME%/lib directory is for?

Comment: The whole purpose is to segregate different jar files in different folders like lib/hibernate , lib/spring .. And by default only lib is part of classpath

Comment: You cannot have subdirectories within WEB-INF/lib. As servlet specification states, only jar files directly under lib (/WEB-INF/lib/*.jar) will be loaded by classloader.

Comment: you could create a link to each jar file, so you still have the jars grouped. but managing the links could be not so easy.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You shouldn't care about how the jar files are segregated into the war file: it's only used by the container. Segregating the jar files could be useful in your source project. But then you just need to have a build process (using ant, gradle, whatever) that copies all the jar files from all the subdirectories into `WEB-INF/lib`. Using ant:

```
<copy todir="web/WEB-INF/lib" flatten="true">
    <fileset dir="lib">
        <include name="**/*.jar"/>
    </fileset>
</copy>
```

Comment: Good idea.  Any idea how one would go about doing this using eclipse without ant?  I presume eclipse's "builders" can be configured to do stuff like this, but can't see anything obvious in the default install.  Perhaps there's a plugin that will do it?

Comment: For eclipse http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14509766/how-to-move-web-inf-lib-folder-to-a-sub-folder-in-a-java-dynamic-web-app

Answer (score 0):

Since things don't care about JAR naming, another alternative is to simply append prefixes to the the JARs (i.e. "spring-OLD JAR NAME.jar") to keep related JARs grouped without folders.