# creating the folder inside the WEB-INF/lib so that all the lib files will be sorted

Tags: jakarta-ee, web-inf

I am working on the `Java EE` project, Not on any framework. When I started working on it, there were only 3 `jar` files. Currently that particular folder has 10 `jar` files and in the future might be more than 25. That's why I want to sort all the lib files.

I googled it, and I got the [this link](http://www.coderanch.com/t/491886/Tomcat/add-folder-WEB-INF-lib) where they said that it can be done but they have not specified that after making that what kind of changes are required. So anyone has an idea what changes required after adding a folder in the lib folder?

Comment: Check the answer to this question, maybe it can be of help.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11296020/including-a-directory-inside-web-inf-lib-in-tomcat-classpath

Comment: Why and where do you want them sorted?

Comment: @JB Nizet sort means, i just need to create the individual folders so that its good to know which `.jar` file in which folder

Comment: Then indeed, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11296020/including-a-directory-inside-web-inf-lib-in-tomcat-classpath

Answer (score 0):

The `war` or `ear` that contains the `WEB-INF` can be assembled by a build infrastructure.
The build infrastructure uses a configuration files to define the dependencie in `WEB-INF`. You can have a look at [Maven](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-pom.html), for instance.

The advantages of a build infrastrucre are the following:

1. Ordering -- You can order the dependencies in the configuration file as you wish ;
2. Documentation -- You provide additional information about the dependencies in the files ;
3. Versioning -- It favors a clean versioning scheme, e.g. `dependency-1.2.3.jar` ;
4. Modularity -- It can automate the build of depedent projects to obtain the latest `jar`.
5. Flexibiliy -- You can automate the packaging of different kinds of sources form different locations, e.g. static html files or images, `jar` from dependent projects, resources files for localizations, etc.

The drawback is clear:

1. Complexity -- The build infrastructure is an additional piece of technolgoy to control in your project.

I would go without a build infrastcture only for very simple projects. The fact that there might be 10-25 dependent jars seem to indicate an already medium project. It might be worth considering this option.